# I'm gettin error default.storage is not a function when i run my react app

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to implement adding images feature in my react project with usage of firebase storage.
This is the error:
Uncaught TypeError: firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.storage is not a function.
This error occurs in firebase configuration file. I used firebase firestore in this project for adding new blogs, and I was adding images through url and everything worked just fine.

Here are my imports:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import "firebase/storage"
```

And instance of storage

```
export const storage = firebase.storage()
```

Answer (score 1):

When using the compatibility library, make sure that all components are imported from the compatibility library.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import "firebase/compat/storage";
//               ^^^^^^
```

The compatibility library is for supporting legacy code. For all new code, you should be using the modern Modular SDK because the legacy Namespaced SDK is deprecated. See the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you are an expo user importing firebase from compat/storage solves the issue

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
```